# Почему на сервере Ubuntu слетают команды которые вносит root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Почему на сервере Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS слетают команды которые вносит root?

Конкретно перестает через время работать команда:

sudo chown -R bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content

Comment: wp или кто-то другой перезаписывает